# Python csv + default dict with multi dimension

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I have a python default dict as shown in below result. I need to print them in a csv file as shown in desired output.

```
print(result_fruit)
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
            {   'word': Counter({   'Tom_success': 5,
                                     'Jerry_Success': 4}),
                'pdf': Counter({   'Tom_success': 1,
                                   'Jerry_success': 3}),
                })
```

Desired output in csv:

```
mime    Tom_success Jerry_success
word      5            4
pdf       1            3
```

Where my output in csv is broken and the cursor doesn't go to next column:

```
mime                    Tom_success     Jerry_success
word                  
5
4  
pdf 
1
3
```

my code:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter =',')
    writer.writerow( ('mime','Tom_success','Jerry_success') )
    for mime in result_fruit:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(mime))
        for category_success in sorted(result_fruit[mime]):
                writer.writerow('{}'.format(result_fruit[mime][category_success]))
```

Comment: `f.write('{}\n'.format(mime))` ?? You write to the file itself and the `csv.writer`? I don't think it will fix everything but it seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row of ouput, call `.writerow()` exactly once. Pass `.writerow()` a list or tuple of the items in that row.

Try this:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('mime', 'Tom_success', 'Jerry_success'))
    for mime, data in result_fruit.items():
        writer.writerow([mime, data['Tom_success'], data['Jerry_success']])
```

Alternatively, you can use `csv.Dictwriter`. Again, call `.writerow()` once for each row of output.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['mime', 'Tom_success', 'Jerry_success'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for mime, data in result_fruit.items():
        row = {'mime': mime}
        row.update(data)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to write the key and the elements on separate lines

```
for mime in result_fruit:
    f.write('{}\n'.format(mime))

    # writes the key, and \n

    for category_success in sorted(result_fruit[mime]):
            writer.writerow('{}'.format(result_fruit[mime][category_success]))

       # does a writerow for each element of the list.
```

The equivalent action, with a regular dictionary and print

```
In [200]: dd = {'word': [5,4], 'pdf':[1,3]}
In [201]: for key in dd:
     ...:     print(key)
     ...:     for v in dd[key]:
     ...:         print(v)
     ...:         
word
5
4
pdf
1
3
```

You want a file write that is more like this:

```
In [205]: for key in dd:
     ...:     print(key, end='\t')
     ...:     for v in dd[key]:
     ...:         print(v, end='\t')
     ...:     print()
     ...:     
word    5   4   
pdf     1   3
```

You could even stick with the `print` function and add `file` parameter.

I don't use the `csv` module enough to suggest a direct solution with that.